# Compilation of Braisos

Tags: talmud-gemara

Mishnah and Tosefta were compiled into methodical masechtos/sedorim and books (as in nowadays physical books). Is there a compilation or list of all the Braisos quoted in Shas Bavli/Yerushalmi?

Comment: If they were compiled, they would be Braisos, would they? ([Beraita from בר outside/wild](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baraita))

Comment: @DoubleAA I did not know that! +1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The book אוצר הברייתות (available in ten volumes on [Hebrewbooks.org](http://www.hebrewbooks.org)) claims to collect all the baraytot (he says over 18,000) from both the Bavli and Yerushalmi, arranged topically. He also gives short notes on each one with references to other places in the literature (such as Tosefta and Midrashim).

The first volume is [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/31240); the others can be searched for easily with the words אוצר הברייתות.